# Two JQuery plugins conflicting on page

Tags: jquery

I'm using an image slider plugin (.nivoSlider) and a responsive menu plugin (.mmenu) on my site and they seem to be conflicting but in a really strange way!

If you visit the site the image slider and menu will load up ok and everything is great.  The problem is if you visit another page and then revisit the index/home page the slider does not load!

It might be worth mentioning that if you press refresh the slider loads ok again!

I have spent hours searching the net for solutions and trying everything but nothing seems to be working.

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be really appreciated.

Here is the url: http://www.paulcrookconsultancy.com/index.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: please insert your whole script in one script tag and put your all js files into end of html before body tag close and then your script and you have type 2 times this line verticalDragMAxheight : 100

Comment: How are you debugging? Do you see errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by replacing the image sliders first line which was...

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

with...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

i get the following error in firebug when visiting the index page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jScrollPane'
```

sounds like you need to include the jScrollPane jquery plugin in your document.

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this answer. This could be the real problem.